# Javascript - Storing Class methods in mulitple files?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Is is possible to have one class and distribute it's methods over multiple files?
My class is now in one file and it's getting to be a long file, that is becoming hard to navigate developing.

I thought of extending a class, but that is building on top of a class. And multiple extended classes don't communicate amongst each other, right?

So the main file would have the constructor and the other files would have one or just a few methods of its class.

Comment: This might be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - if you have a class so large that you need it in different files for readability reasons, it sounds like the class is badly designed. Trust me, I know - had one that was 7000 lines long. After some refactoring it's "only" 2400 lines now and requires substantially more refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to properties of the prototype, just like in the old days when `function`s were used instead of `class`es - import the functions from the other files, and after the class is defined, assign the properties:

```
// main.js
import method1 from './method1';
import method2 from './method2';
// or use require() syntax, depending on how your environment is set up
class Foo {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // ...
  }
}
Foo.prototype.method1 = method1;
Foo.prototype.method2 = method2;
```

```
// method1.js
export default function() {
  console.log('method1 running for ' + this.name);
};
```

Both `method1` and `method2` will still be able to reference `this` to refer to the instance, just like they were defined as a method directly inside `Foo`.

You can use `import` syntax with ES6 modules (eg `<script type="module"`) or in a module bundler system like Webpack. In node, import using `require(path)` and export by assigning to `module.exports` or properties of `module.exports`.

Comment: Thanks @certainperformance. Could you add to your answer that the scripts should be loaded with the type attribute `module`? so `<script type=module src"./main.js"> ` Otherwise you get an import/export error in the console

Answer (score 1):

If a single class is getting so big that you're worried the file containing it is getting too big, I'd say the best thing you can do is refactor the class into smaller classes that are more focussed on solving a single problem.

If you can't do that, then you can have the main class's file create the class:

```
class Example {
}
```

...and then have multiple files that add methods to its prototype:

```
Example.prototype.doThis = function doThis() {
    // ...
};
Example.prototype.doThat = function doThat() {
    // ...
};
```

You lose the ability to use `super` in those methods, but other than that it works.

> I thought of extending a class, but that is building on top of a class. And multiple extended classes don't communicate amongst each other, right?

I'm not sure what you mean about not being able to communicate between superclasses and subclasses. The instance data is common to all, and they can use each other's methods.